# UTF-8 and multilingual website

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, multilingual

I've been reading around with UTF-8, but I need some advice.

Example. I have a form, where a user can input text. This can be English but Japanese also. The next page, outputs the text and stores it in a DB.

Everything is (or should be) defined as UTF-8. It's all working fine, untill we're adding Arabic or Japanese letters `キ`. These letters become (if I got it right) Unicode form `%u06458`.

Now the thing is, I know how to output these letters:

```
$x= preg_replace('/%u([0-9A-F]+)/', '&#x$1;', $x);
```

That will make it UTF-8 code and output the Japenese letter just fine.

But my question is, I want to verify the length and store it in my DB. But one Japanese letter is already 8-bit compared to a normal letter that is 1-bit.

1. How should I check the 'text' length ? Like `AA = 2` and `キキ = 2`.
2. Will such letters always be stored as an 8-bit `%u06458` in my datbase ? What if I have a text that has 2000 words in Japanese (2000*8bits) ? That's 8 times more than a text in English.
3. Any general tips ?

Answer (score 2):

PHP has functions that specifically handle multi-byte (i.e. Unicode) strings.

Check the [Multibyte string help](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) and the [Multibyte string functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php) in the PHP manual.

As for your questions:

1. You can check the text length using [mb_strlen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php)
2. You can store the multibyte characters directly in the database, without transcoding them. Each multibyte character occupies 2 bytes
3. Use the PHP multibyte functions to handle these strings :)

Comment: Yes, to store it in the database, one has to set the charset before working with the db. In mysqli this would be `$db->set_charset('utf8');` for example.

Comment: mb_strlen works fine with `ß` but with `م `he keeps returning 8 as a result. Unless I'm doing something wrong

`$strLength=mb_strlen($str, 'UTF-8');`

Comment: @Nicolas. - The code `echo mb_strlen('م');` returns 2 in my test. Did you store the PHP file in the UTF-8 format (the file format not the encoding declaration)?

Comment: @martinstoeckli No I write it trough a form. It becomes Unicode %u0645 on the next page, so I transform it to UTF-8 with the code here above (preg_replace). That's probably where the problem is. But if I print it after the preg_replace, it's م

Comment: @Nicolas. - There should be no need for the regex, if you use UTF-8 for the page and for the database. I tried to point out the necessary steps in this small [article](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/php/php.html#utf8).

Comment: @martinstoeckli it's all working fine with é and ß, but with Japanese and Arabic letters the form returns Unicode (%u0645). The ß for example stays ß on the next form page. I don't know why, all (headers) are set to UTF-8 and it works for other letters.

Comment: @Nicolas. - Could you provide an url that demonstrates the isolated problem?

Comment: @martinstoeckli I've found out that it is actually a javascript problem, ajax seems to be doing it. But still, I couldn't find a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16962354/ajax-post-method-with-utf-8

Answer (score 0):

All the `mb_...` functions are for multi-byte characters.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php

There's a `mb_strlen` in there.