# AJAX: post method with UTF-8

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, utf-8, utf

I'm trying to send data as `UTF-8` over Ajax, but it's changing some data in `unicode`. I'll explain it with two short examples:

A simple POST (without ajax)

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" method="POST" action="test2.php">
<input type="text" class="" name="text">
<input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Meta and PHP headers are always set:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">

header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

If I submit an Arabic letter (`ب`), and use `strlen()` it will return 3. If I use `mb_strlen()` it will return 1. This is all good as it should be.

Now the Ajax version. The form, headers and meta are the same. But onsubmit() calls this ajax in Javascript:

```
... (initiating HttpReq)
self.xmlHttpReq.open('POST', strURL, true);
self.xmlHttpReq.setRequestHeader("charset", "utf-8");
self.xmlHttpReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); 
...
if (self.xmlHttpReq.readyState == 4) { ... }
```

Now the same test gives for `strlen()` 6 and for `mb_strlen()` also 6. The ب was actually converted to `6%u0628` somewhere in the Ajax process.. And this does not happen with a normal `POST` (example one).

What am I forgetting/doing wrong in the Ajax process ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i use alot ajax and always use only utf8 and never had a problem , i'm mostly on chrome and safari ios

maybe try changing ur ajax script by removing all the headers.and using the new `FormData` (should work on most modern browsers) ... sure not on all.

`document.forms[0]` means it takes all the fields from first form in your page.
else give it an id and call `document.getElementById('myform')`
i also don't use anymore `readyState`... `onload`

to return the response in postresponsefunction u write `this.response`

```
var fd=new FormData(document.forms[0]),
c=new XMLHttpRequest();
c.open('POST',strURL);
c.onload=postresponsefunction;
c.send(fd);
```

here is a complet working php script with post & ajax file is named 'test.php'

```
<?php
if($_REQUEST){
print_r($_REQUEST);
}else{
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>postajax</title>
<script>
var 
rf=function(){
 document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerText=this.response;
},
sf=function(e){
 e.preventDefault();e.stopPropagation();
 var fd=new FormData(document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0]),
 c=new XMLHttpRequest();
 c.open('POST','test.php');
 c.onload=rf;
 c.send(fd);
};
window.onload=function(){
 document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].onsubmit=sf;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="text" name="mytext"><input type="submit" value="submit">
</form><div></div>
</body>
</html>
<?php
}
?>
```

ie

```
if (!window.XMLHttpRequest) {
  window.XMLHttpRequest = function() {
    return new ActiveXObject(”Microsoft.XMLHTTP”);
  };
}
```

Comment: Your script seems to be working fine. Thx! Do you know on which browsers FormData doesn't work ? I'd like to use it, but also need it to work on most browsers (and old browsers)

Comment: yeah modern browser supports this older one not.this is XHR2 and FormData http://caniuse.com/xhr2 and here is a polyfill forFormData for other browsers. https://github.com/francois2metz/html5-formdata

Comment: And how to you handle it with older browsers ?

Comment: if something is not working u need to find the equivalent polyfill.in your case the polyfill for FormData... xhr really works on 90% of  the  computers now.also works on latest ie...

Comment: i would tell the older browser to download a new browser.we need to get a standard.and this will be thenew standard.keep stuff simple.

Comment: Yes it's true. However my script has to run on IE8 aswell because many of my users still have IE8 (like companies that have customized IE's). I'll figure it out. Thanks for your help !

Comment: i'm sure there is also a FormData polyfill for ie8,and in ie 8 u prolly also need to change a little the xhr script ... i add the code

Comment: I'll have to look at it. Or in IE8 I'll have to load the old script I'm using now. At least it works a little then