# How are arabic letters (correctly) stored in mysql ? ب or &#x0628;

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

This might be a dummy question, but I'm a little lost in it.

How are Arabic questions exactly stored in a database ?

Let's take `ب`, if I insert that directly in the DB it becomes `?`. Not good.

If I use a form (and php script) and store it as UTF-8, it is stored like `&#x0628;`. I can read it out and print it out, all good.

So my question is, are Arabic (and Japanese,...) letters always stored likes this in a mysql database `&#x0628;` ? Or should I change a setting somewhere and it should look like ب when I'm browsing the database?

It's just to define the length of my rows (varchars/chars) in the database...

DB set to utf8_general

Site fully UTF8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try to store a UTF-8 encoded character and it becomes `?`, this means MySQL did not understand or support the encoding in which you sent the character. The column needs to be set to store `utf8` data (better `utf8mb4` if supported) and the *connection encoding* needs to be set to the correct encoding to inform MySQL *in what encoding you're sending data* to it.

If you get HTML entities from a form submission, this means the browser tried to send data in an encoding which did not support that particular character; therefore it had to fall back on HTML entities to encode the character. You need to set the encoding declarations correctly to tell the browser it should send UTF-8 encoded text to the server.

See [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/) and/or [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through) for how to do all this.

Comment: It's working now! I forgot to set the field UTF-8 aswell. And my Ajax script isn't sending UTF8 for a reason I still don't know http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16962354/ajax-post-method-with-utf-8